# change image on button when pressed

Tags: android, image, button

I have a button that changes images when pressed, the problem is that I want to change it between more than just 2.

The button is set up to function as the regular image, and while it's being pressed, it's replaced with a slightly darker version of the same image.

Unfortunately, I want to have more than one base image.  I want to implement 9 different base images (which will be changed by code), and 9 respective images to display while the button is pressed.  The drawable XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbrownie" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/brownie0"/>
</selector>
```

but I want to set @drawable/pressedbrownie to be one of 9 different values, based on whatever the program decides, and same thing with @drawable/brownie0.

Can the primaryPage.java file detect when the button is being pressed, or do I have some XML magic to learn?

Comment: Do you want to display any of the 9 images randomly when button is pressed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. If you're more comfortable sticking with XML, you could create 9
   different State List selector XMLs (one for each image pair), 
   and then swap which selector file is being used by the button as
   needed.
2. You can programmatically create a StateListDrawable to assign to
   the button as needed.

**Option 1:**
Create a series of State Lists.

brownie_selector0.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbrownie0" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/brownie0"/>
</selector>
```

brownie_selector1.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbrownie1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/brownie1"/>
</selector>
```

...and so on.

Then change which State List is assigned to the button. For example using a switch:

```
...
Button brownieButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myBrownieButton);
switch (brownieType) {  // brownieType would be an int indicating which State List is needed
case 0:
    brownieButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.brownie_selector0));
    break;
case 1:
    brownieButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.brownie_selector1));
    break;
...
}
```

**Option 2**
Do it all in code.
First create SparseIntArrays of your drawables:

```
int drawableId;
String drawableName;
SparseIntArray brownieNormal = new SparseIntArray(totalNumberOfBrownies);
SparseIntArray browniePressed = new SparseIntArray(totalNumberOfBrownies);
// iterate through all the required brownie pairs
for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfBrownies; i++) {
    // generate the required file name
    drawableName = "brownie" + i;  
    // find the id of the required drawable using the generated file name
    drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    // put the resulting drawable id into the SparseIntArray
    brownieNormal.put(n, drawableId);
    // repeat for the pressed images
    drawableName = "pressedBrownie" + i;
    drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    browniePressed.put(n, drawableId);
}
```

Then create and assign a suitable StateListDrawable as required.

```
private StateListDrawable mBrownieStates;
...

// method to deal with when mBrownieType changes
private void changeBrownieButtonStateListDrawable(int brownieType);
    // reset mBrownieStates to a fresh StateListDrawable
    mBrownieStates = new StateListDrawable();
    // add the drawable for the pressed state
    mBrownieStates.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, browniePressed.get(brownieType));
    // add the drawable for the default state
    mBrownieStates.addState(new int[] {}, brownieNormal.get(brownieType));

    // update the button with the newly defined StateListDrawable
    Button brownieButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myBrownieButton);
    brownieButton.setBackground(mBrownieStates);
}
```

Comment: Following option 1: when I get to the part where I implement the switch case, `brownieButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.brownie_selector0));` throws an error, with brownie_selector(X) not being resolved.  Naturally the XML files are named identically across the drawable DPI folders.  The funny thing is, they're still seen as a valid resource.  Trying instead with `brownieButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brownie_selector0);` just results in crashes on run with a stack overflow

Comment: To help pinpoint what's going on update your question to include revised code you've tried and the resulting LogCats. More info the better. I've found with my own questions, that the problem often isn't where I thought it was, and others spot it in the extra info.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I found the error.  It turns out that a combination of bad variable naming on my part, and bad IDE renaming caused the XML file to call itself in an infinite loop

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 0):

You can define 9 different `selectors(xml drawables)` under `res/drawable` folder, like your current `selector(xml drawable)`. Set different `drawables` to their pressed states.

And use one of these selectors by programmatically setting them as the background.

```
// I assume you have a button an instance of Button in your layout with id button.
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
// choose on of the selectors with an if/else or switch/case statement 
// and set as the background of your button.
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_1);
// or 
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_9);
```